# What does this use case mean

Tags: documentation, uml, specifications, requirements, use-case

So i am creating a use case specification, I am just a bit confused, There is a vending machine which allows the actor to choose from two different payment methods, so actor can pay by card or pay by coin, is the following specification correct for this scenario?

```
1. Include [Payment Acceptance Use Case ID]
  1.1 Actor Select Card to Pay with 
  1.1.1 Include [Pay By Card Use Case ID]
  1.1.2 Actor enters card
  1.1.3 System validates card
  1.1.4 Drink is dispensed 
  1.2 Actor Selects Coins to pay with
  1.2.1 Include [Pay By Coins Use Case ID]
  1.2.2 Actor enters coins
  1.2.3 Drink is dispensed
```

Does this use case specification justify the scenario that Actor has the choice to choose to pay with either card or coins is the use case specification saying that the Actor must pay by card first then pay by coins?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this syntax for a use case, but the way these options are presented currently is logically flawed: it is assumed that 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, and 1.1.4 are sequential (as would be 1.2.1, 1.2.2, and 1.2.3), so one would assume that 1.1 and 1.2 should also be sequential.

Again, I don't know the standard well, but it seems to me that a possible fix would be to indent the third-level steps and put `OR` at the end of 1.1, like so:

```
1. Include [Payment Acceptance Use Case ID]
  1.1 Actor Select Card to Pay with OR
    1.1.1 Include [Pay By Card Use Case ID]
    1.1.2 Actor enters card
    1.1.3 System validates card
    1.1.4 Drink is dispensed 
  1.2 Actor Selects Coins to pay with
    1.2.1 Include [Pay By Coins Use Case ID]
    1.2.2 Actor enters coins
    1.2.3 Drink is dispensed
```

Answer (score 0):

See this URL for an example of a use case template: http://alistair.cockburn.us/Basic+use+case+template

Your 1.2 till 1.2.3 would be listed under "variations"